# Memory leak on Lists

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm suffering a memory leak on a ListView. I know very well that optimization of lists in Android is a very common topic and there are a lot of tutorials in Internet and questions in stack overflow about it, but none seems to solve my problem.

The problem is that when click on Back key, the memory consumed by the views of the rows, isn't "freed"

I have shortened my getView implementation to this, so I'm not filling information, just inflating the row layout:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
    }
    return v;
}
```

The adapter's constructor is also, extremely simple, so I'not saving anything on global variables, neither the information to fill the rows (which is within p_items):

```
public IconListView(Context p_context, int p_textViewResourceId,   ArrayList<IconListViewRow> p_items,) {
    super(p_context, p_textViewResourceId, p_items);    
}
```

The layout of the row is quite complex, it consists on some text views nested in Linear and Relative layouts, so it takes a large amount of memory (let's say 500 Kb a row). However, if I reduce the complexity to only a linear layout with some text views, the amount of memory consumed is reduced significantly, but anyways, is never "freed" when I click on Back button, so the memory occupied by my application grows to infinity.

Any tutorial that I have read seems to take care of this. There are clever improvements for performance of lists, like ViewHolder, but none related with this. In fact, they use quite simple layouts for rows, so you cannot appreciate an alarming consumption of memory, although anyways, it always grows to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

I you think your doing everything correctly already, then I suggest that you perform a memory analysis. I'm sure that it's a case of you referencing the view or it's view group somewhere that's preventing your list from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

When back button is hit, your activity and its content is still alive and is not disposed.  If you like to free memory in this case, you have to react in onPause() method. As first meassure I would try to return 0 from your list adapter and  notify list of changed data.
If it does not helps -  then you may have to dispose list completely.

But you must be aware, that you buying memory with longer startup time in case user calls for  activity again

Comment: _italic_ When back button is hit, your activity and its content is still alive and is not disposed _italic_ I don't understand what you claim. Activities are kept in a stack when you launch an Intent, but, when you click on 'Back', an activity must be dropped and all its resources, released.

Comment: Actually it is not. onPause() is called,   but destruction is posponed to some later time.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, thank you. Anyways, I have added a button to the layout which applies a clear() to the adapter. This operation removes all the rows as expected, but memory isn't freed, so @Filip must be on the right track, some variable is kept by Android.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out something relevant. When you use customized components for the layout of your rows, like:

```
MyTextView extends TextView
MyButton   extends Button
```

the memory is leaked. The memory consumed by my applications has reduced a lot of since I gave up those components on ListViews.

This happens, at least, with my customized components. I cannot assume that this happens for every customized component, maybe mine have something wrong, but be careful with this.